# File::files() response returns array of empty objects

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to fetch a list of files in my Laravel application through the Files facade, but it's not working as expected.

```
$path = storage_path('path/to/folder/' . $request->folder);
$files = File::files($path);
return response()->json($files, 200);
```

This is the code I'm running. There are currently 5 files in the directory I'm using to test this out.

The response shows the correct amount of files as objects inside an array, but all of them are empty.

[image]

The path I'm aiming at is correct, the files exist and adding/removing files reflects as expected in the response. But I don't understand why the objects are empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: What class type does `File` return, has it any visible public properties? If not then `json_encoding` such a file will return an empty notation - [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get information about the files in the directory by accessing the properties and methods of [`SplFileInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) objects.

```
$path = storage_path('path/to/folder/' . $request->folder);
$files = File::files($path);

$fileDetails = [];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileDetails[] = [
        'name' => $file->getFilename(),
        'path' => $file->getRealPath(),
        'size' => $file->getSize(),
        'lastModified' => $file->getMTime(),
    ];
}

return response()->json($fileDetails, 200);
```